Problems using FFmpeg / libavfilter for adding overlay to grabbed frames
On Windows with latest FFmpeg / libav (full build, non-free) a C/C++ app reads YUV420P frames from a frame grabber card.
A bitmap (BGR24) overlay image from file should be drawn on every frame for the first 20 seconds via libavfilter. First, the BGR24 overlay image becomes converted via format filter to YUV420P. Then the YUV420P frame from frame grabber and the YUV420P overlay frame are pushed into the overlay filter.
FFmpeg / libavfilter does not report any errors or warnings in console / log. Trying to get the filtered frame out of the graph via  av_buffersink_get_frame results in an EAGAIN return code.
The frames from the frame grabber card are fine, they could become encoded or written to a .yuv file. The overlay frame itself is fine too.
This is the complete private code (prototype - no style, memory leaks, ...):
#define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
#include <Windows.h>

#include "../fgproto/include/SDL/SDL_video.h"
#include <tisudshl.h>

using namespace _DSHOWLIB_NAMESPACE;

#ifdef _WIN32
//Windows
extern "C" {
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libswscale/swscale.h"
#include "libavdevice/avdevice.h"
#include "libavfilter/avfilter.h"
#include <libavutil/log.h>
#include <libavutil/mem.h>
#include "libavfilter/buffersink.h"
#include "libavfilter/buffersrc.h"
#include "libavutil/opt.h"
#include "libavutil/hwcontext_qsv.h"
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
};
#endif
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

void uSleep(double waitTimeInUs, LARGE_INTEGER frequency)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER startTime, currentTime;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&startTime);

    if (waitTimeInUs > 16500.0)
        Sleep(1);

    do
    {
        YieldProcessor();
        //Sleep(0);
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&currentTime);
    }
    while (waitTimeInUs > (currentTime.QuadPart - startTime.QuadPart) * 1000000.0 / frequency.QuadPart);
}

void check_error(int ret)
{
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        char errbuf[128];
        int tmp = errno;
        av_strerror(ret, errbuf, sizeof(errbuf));
        std::cerr << "Error: " << errbuf << '\n';
        //exit(1);
    }
}

bool _isRunning = true;

void swap_uv_planes(AVFrame* frame)
{
    uint8_t* temp_plane = frame->data[1]; 
    frame->data[1] = frame->data[2]; 
    frame->data[2] = temp_plane; 
}

typedef struct
{
    const AVClass* avclass;
} MyFilterGraphContext;

static constexpr AVClass my_filter_graph_class = 
{
    .class_name = "MyFilterGraphContext",
    .item_name = av_default_item_name,
    .option = NULL,
    .version = LIBAVUTIL_VERSION_INT,
};

MyFilterGraphContext* init_log_context()
{
    MyFilterGraphContext* ctx = static_cast<MyFilterGraphContext*>(av_mallocz(sizeof(*ctx)));

    if (!ctx)
    {
        av_log(nullptr, AV_LOG_ERROR, "Unable to allocate MyFilterGraphContext\n");
        return nullptr;
    }

    ctx->avclass = &my_filter_graph_class;
    return ctx;
}

int init_overlay_filter(AVFilterGraph** graph, AVFilterContext** src_ctx, AVFilterContext** overlay_src_ctx,
                        AVFilterContext** sink_ctx)
{
    AVFilterGraph* filter_graph;
    AVFilterContext* buffersrc_ctx;
    AVFilterContext* overlay_buffersrc_ctx;
    AVFilterContext* buffersink_ctx;
    AVFilterContext* overlay_ctx;
    AVFilterContext* format_ctx;

    const AVFilter* buffersrc, * buffersink, * overlay_buffersrc, * overlay_filter, * format_filter;
    int ret;

    // Create the filter graph
    filter_graph = avfilter_graph_alloc();
    if (!filter_graph)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create filter graph.\n");
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    }

    // Create buffer source filter for main video
    buffersrc = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
    if (!buffersrc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to find buffer filter.\n");
        return AVERROR_FILTER_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    // Create buffer source filter for overlay image
    overlay_buffersrc = avfilter_get_by_name("buffer");
    if (!overlay_buffersrc)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to find buffer filter.\n");
        return AVERROR_FILTER_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    // Create buffer sink filter
    buffersink = avfilter_get_by_name("buffersink");
    if (!buffersink)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to find buffersink filter.\n");
        return AVERROR_FILTER_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    // Create overlay filter
    overlay_filter = avfilter_get_by_name("overlay");
    if (!overlay_filter)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to find overlay filter.\n");
        return AVERROR_FILTER_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    // Create format filter
    format_filter = avfilter_get_by_name("format");
    if (!format_filter)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to find format filter.\n");
        return AVERROR_FILTER_NOT_FOUND;
    }

    // Initialize the main video buffer source
    char args[512];

    // Initialize the overlay buffer source
    snprintf(args, sizeof(args), "video_size=165x165:pix_fmt=bgr24:time_base=1/25:pixel_aspect=1/1"); 

    ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&overlay_buffersrc_ctx, overlay_buffersrc, nullptr, args, nullptr,
        filter_graph);

    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create buffer source filter for overlay.\n");
        return ret;
    }

    snprintf(args, sizeof(args), "video_size=1920x1080:pix_fmt=yuv420p:time_base=1/25:pixel_aspect=1/1");

    ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersrc_ctx, buffersrc, nullptr, args, nullptr, filter_graph);

    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create buffer source filter for main video.\n");
        return ret;
    }

    // Initialize the format filter to convert overlay image to yuv420p
    snprintf(args, sizeof(args), "pix_fmts=yuv420p");

    ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&format_ctx, format_filter, nullptr, args, nullptr, filter_graph);

    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create format filter.\n");
        return ret;
    }

    // Initialize the overlay filter
    ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&overlay_ctx, overlay_filter, nullptr, "W-w:H-h:enable='between(t,0,20)':format=yuv420", nullptr, filter_graph);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create overlay filter.\n");
        return ret;
    }

    // Initialize the buffer sink
    ret = avfilter_graph_create_filter(&buffersink_ctx, buffersink, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, filter_graph);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create buffer sink filter.\n");
        return ret;
    }

    // Connect the filters
    ret = avfilter_link(overlay_buffersrc_ctx, 0, format_ctx, 0);

    if (ret >= 0)
    {
        ret = avfilter_link(buffersrc_ctx, 0, overlay_ctx, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to configure filter graph.\n");
        return ret;
    }


    if (ret >= 0)
    {
        ret = avfilter_link(format_ctx, 0, overlay_ctx, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to configure filter graph.\n");
        return ret;
    }

    if (ret >= 0)
    {
        if ((ret = avfilter_link(overlay_ctx, 0, buffersink_ctx, 0)) < 0)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unable to link filter graph.\n");
            return ret;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to configure filter graph.\n");
        return ret;
    }

    MyFilterGraphContext* log_ctx = init_log_context();

    // Configure the filter graph
    if ((ret = avfilter_graph_config(filter_graph, log_ctx)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to configure filter graph.\n");
        return ret;
    }

    *graph = filter_graph;
    *src_ctx = buffersrc_ctx;
    *overlay_src_ctx = overlay_buffersrc_ctx;
    *sink_ctx = buffersink_ctx;

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    unsigned int videoIndex = 0;

    avdevice_register_all();

    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_TRACE);

    const AVInputFormat* pFrameGrabberInputFormat = av_find_input_format("dshow");

    constexpr int frameGrabberPixelWidth = 1920;
    constexpr int frameGrabberPixelHeight = 1080;
    constexpr int frameGrabberFrameRate = 25;
    constexpr AVPixelFormat frameGrabberPixelFormat = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;

    char shortStringBuffer[32];

    AVDictionary* pFrameGrabberOptions = nullptr;

    _snprintf_s(shortStringBuffer, sizeof(shortStringBuffer), "%dx%d", frameGrabberPixelWidth, frameGrabberPixelHeight);
    av_dict_set(&pFrameGrabberOptions, "video_size", shortStringBuffer, 0);

    _snprintf_s(shortStringBuffer, sizeof(shortStringBuffer), "%d", frameGrabberFrameRate);

    av_dict_set(&pFrameGrabberOptions, "framerate", shortStringBuffer, 0);
    av_dict_set(&pFrameGrabberOptions, "pixel_format", "yuv420p", 0);
    av_dict_set(&pFrameGrabberOptions, "rtbufsize", "128M", 0);

    AVFormatContext* pFrameGrabberFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();

    pFrameGrabberFormatContext->flags = AVFMT_FLAG_NOBUFFER | AVFMT_FLAG_FLUSH_PACKETS;

    if (avformat_open_input(&pFrameGrabberFormatContext, "video=MZ0380 PCI, Analog 01 Capture",
                            pFrameGrabberInputFormat, &pFrameGrabberOptions) != 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't open input stream." << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    if (avformat_find_stream_info(pFrameGrabberFormatContext, nullptr) < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't find stream information." << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    bool foundVideoStream = false;

    for (unsigned int loop_videoIndex = 0; loop_videoIndex < pFrameGrabberFormatContext->nb_streams; loop_videoIndex++)
    {
        if (pFrameGrabberFormatContext->streams[loop_videoIndex]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            videoIndex = loop_videoIndex;
            foundVideoStream = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!foundVideoStream)
    {
        std::cerr << "Couldn't find a video stream." << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    const AVCodec* pFrameGrabberCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(
        pFrameGrabberFormatContext->streams[videoIndex]->codecpar->codec_id);

    AVCodecContext* pFrameGrabberCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(pFrameGrabberCodec);

    if (pFrameGrabberCodec == nullptr)
    {
        std::cerr << "Codec not found." << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    pFrameGrabberCodecContext->pix_fmt = frameGrabberPixelFormat;
    pFrameGrabberCodecContext->width = frameGrabberPixelWidth;
    pFrameGrabberCodecContext->height = frameGrabberPixelHeight;

    int ret = avcodec_open2(pFrameGrabberCodecContext, pFrameGrabberCodec, nullptr);

    if (ret < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not open pVideoCodec." << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    const char* outputFilePath = "c:\\temp\\output.mp4";
    constexpr int outputWidth = frameGrabberPixelWidth;
    constexpr int outputHeight = frameGrabberPixelHeight;
    constexpr int outputFrameRate = frameGrabberFrameRate;

    SwsContext* img_convert_ctx = sws_getContext(frameGrabberPixelWidth, frameGrabberPixelHeight,
                                                 frameGrabberPixelFormat, outputWidth, outputHeight, AV_PIX_FMT_NV12,
                                                 SWS_BICUBIC, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr);

    constexpr double frameTimeinUs = 1000000.0 / frameGrabberFrameRate;

    LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
    LARGE_INTEGER lastTime, currentTime;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&lastTime);

    //SDL----------------------------

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_EVENTS))
    {
        printf("Could not initialize SDL - %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_Window* screen = SDL_CreateWindow("3P FrameGrabber SuperApp", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                          frameGrabberPixelWidth, frameGrabberPixelHeight,
                                          SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    if (!screen)
    {
        printf("SDL: could not set video mode - exiting:%s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(screen, -1, 0);

    if (!renderer)
    {
        printf("SDL: could not create renderer - exiting:%s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer, SDL_PIXELFORMAT_YV12, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,
                                             frameGrabberPixelWidth, frameGrabberPixelHeight);

    if (!texture)
    {
        printf("SDL: could not create texture - exiting:%s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return -1;
    }

    SDL_Event event;

    //SDL End------------------------

    const AVCodec* pVideoCodec = avcodec_find_encoder_by_name("h264_qsv");

    if (!pVideoCodec)
    {
        std::cerr << "Codec not found" << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    AVCodecContext* pVideoCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(pVideoCodec);

    if (!pVideoCodecContext)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not allocate video pVideoCodec context" << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    AVBufferRef* pHardwareDeviceContextRef = nullptr;

    ret = av_hwdevice_ctx_create(&pHardwareDeviceContextRef, AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_QSV,
                                 "PCI\\VEN_8086&DEV_5912&SUBSYS_310217AA&REV_04\\3&11583659&0&10", nullptr, 0);
    check_error(ret);

    pVideoCodecContext->bit_rate = static_cast<int64_t>(outputWidth * outputHeight) * 2;
    pVideoCodecContext->width = outputWidth;
    pVideoCodecContext->height = outputHeight;
    pVideoCodecContext->framerate = {outputFrameRate, 1};
    pVideoCodecContext->time_base = {1, outputFrameRate};
    pVideoCodecContext->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_QSV;
    pVideoCodecContext->max_b_frames = 0;

    AVBufferRef* pHardwareFramesContextRef = av_hwframe_ctx_alloc(pHardwareDeviceContextRef);

    AVHWFramesContext* pHardwareFramesContext = reinterpret_cast<AVHWFramesContext*>(pHardwareFramesContextRef->data);

    pHardwareFramesContext->format = AV_PIX_FMT_QSV;
    pHardwareFramesContext->sw_format = AV_PIX_FMT_NV12;
    pHardwareFramesContext->width = outputWidth;
    pHardwareFramesContext->height = outputHeight;
    pHardwareFramesContext->initial_pool_size = 20;

    ret = av_hwframe_ctx_init(pHardwareFramesContextRef);
    check_error(ret);

    pVideoCodecContext->hw_device_ctx = nullptr;
    pVideoCodecContext->hw_frames_ctx = av_buffer_ref(pHardwareFramesContextRef);

    ret = avcodec_open2(pVideoCodecContext, pVideoCodec, nullptr); //&pVideoOptionsDict);
    check_error(ret);

    AVFormatContext* pVideoFormatContext = nullptr;

    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&pVideoFormatContext, nullptr, nullptr, outputFilePath);

    if (!pVideoFormatContext)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not create output context" << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    const AVOutputFormat* pVideoOutputFormat = pVideoFormatContext->oformat;

    if (pVideoFormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
    {
        pVideoCodecContext->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    }

    const AVStream* pVideoStream = avformat_new_stream(pVideoFormatContext, pVideoCodec);

    if (!pVideoStream)
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not allocate stream" << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    ret = avcodec_parameters_from_context(pVideoStream->codecpar, pVideoCodecContext);

    check_error(ret);

    if (!(pVideoOutputFormat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
    {
        ret = avio_open(&pVideoFormatContext->pb, outputFilePath, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        check_error(ret);
    }

    ret = avformat_write_header(pVideoFormatContext, nullptr);

    check_error(ret);

    AVFrame* pHardwareFrame = av_frame_alloc();

    if (av_hwframe_get_buffer(pVideoCodecContext->hw_frames_ctx, pHardwareFrame, 0) < 0)
    {
        std::cerr << "Error allocating a hw frame" << '\n';
        return -1;
    }

    AVFrame* pFrameGrabberFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    AVPacket* pFrameGrabberPacket = av_packet_alloc();

    AVPacket* pVideoPacket = av_packet_alloc();
    AVFrame* pVideoFrame = av_frame_alloc();

    AVFrame* pSwappedFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    av_frame_get_buffer(pSwappedFrame, 32);

    INT64 frameCount = 0;

    pFrameGrabberCodecContext->time_base = {1, frameGrabberFrameRate};

    AVFilterContext* buffersrc_ctx = nullptr;
    AVFilterContext* buffersink_ctx = nullptr;
    AVFilterContext* overlay_src_ctx = nullptr;
    AVFilterGraph* filter_graph = nullptr;

    if ((ret = init_overlay_filter(&filter_graph, &buffersrc_ctx, &overlay_src_ctx, &buffersink_ctx)) < 0)
    {
        return ret;
    }

    // Load overlay image
    AVFormatContext* overlay_fmt_ctx = nullptr;
    AVCodecContext* overlay_codec_ctx = nullptr;
    const AVCodec* overlay_codec = nullptr;
    AVFrame* overlay_frame = nullptr;
    AVDictionary* overlay_options = nullptr;

    const char* overlay_image_filename = "c:\\temp\\overlay.bmp";

    av_dict_set(&overlay_options, "video_size", "165x165", 0);
    av_dict_set(&overlay_options, "pixel_format", "bgr24", 0);

    if ((ret = avformat_open_input(&overlay_fmt_ctx, overlay_image_filename, nullptr, &overlay_options)) < 0)
    {
        return ret;
    }

    if ((ret = avformat_find_stream_info(overlay_fmt_ctx, nullptr)) < 0)
    {
        return ret;
    }

    int overlay_video_stream_index = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < overlay_fmt_ctx->nb_streams; i++)
    {
        if (overlay_fmt_ctx->streams[i]->codecpar->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
        {
            overlay_video_stream_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (overlay_video_stream_index == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    overlay_codec = avcodec_find_decoder(overlay_fmt_ctx->streams[overlay_video_stream_index]->codecpar->codec_id);

    if (!overlay_codec)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Overlay codec not found.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    overlay_codec_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(overlay_codec);

    if (!overlay_codec_ctx)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate overlay codec context.\n");
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    }

    avcodec_parameters_to_context(overlay_codec_ctx, overlay_fmt_ctx->streams[overlay_video_stream_index]->codecpar);

    if ((ret = avcodec_open2(overlay_codec_ctx, overlay_codec, nullptr)) < 0)
    {
        return ret;
    }

    overlay_frame = av_frame_alloc();

    if (!overlay_frame)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate overlay frame.\n");
        return AVERROR(ENOMEM);
    }

    AVPacket* overlay_packet = av_packet_alloc();

    // Read frames from the file
    while (av_read_frame(overlay_fmt_ctx, overlay_packet) >= 0)
    {
        if (overlay_packet->stream_index == overlay_video_stream_index)
        {
            ret = avcodec_send_packet(overlay_codec_ctx, overlay_packet);

            if (ret < 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            ret = avcodec_receive_frame(overlay_codec_ctx, overlay_frame);
            if (ret >= 0)
            {
                
                break; // We only need the first frame for the overlay
            }

            if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
            {
                continue;
            }

            break;
        }

        av_packet_unref(overlay_packet);
    }

    av_packet_unref(overlay_packet);

    while (_isRunning)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0)
        {
            switch (event.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                _isRunning = false;
                break;
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
                    _isRunning = false;
                break;
            default: ;
            }
        }

        if (av_read_frame(pFrameGrabberFormatContext, pFrameGrabberPacket) == 0)
        {
            if (pFrameGrabberPacket->stream_index == videoIndex)
            {
                ret = avcodec_send_packet(pFrameGrabberCodecContext, pFrameGrabberPacket);

                if (ret < 0)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Error sending a packet for decoding!" << '\n';
                    return -1;
                }

                ret = avcodec_receive_frame(pFrameGrabberCodecContext, pFrameGrabberFrame);

                if (ret != 0)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Receiving frame failed!" << '\n';
                    return -1;
                }

                if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR(AVERROR_EOF))
                {
                    std::cout << "End of stream detected. Exiting now." << '\n';
                    return 0;
                }

                if (ret != 0)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Decode Error!" << '\n';
                    return -1;
                }

                // Feed the frame into the filter graph
                if (av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(buffersrc_ctx, pFrameGrabberFrame, AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_KEEP_REF) < 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error while feeding the filtergraph\n");
                    break;
                }

                // Push the overlay frame to the overlay_src_ctx
                ret = av_buffersrc_add_frame_flags(overlay_src_ctx, overlay_frame, AV_BUFFERSRC_FLAG_KEEP_REF);
                if (ret < 0)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Error while feeding the filtergraph\n");
                    break;
                }                           

                // Pull filtered frame from the filter graph
                AVFrame* filtered_frame = av_frame_alloc();

                ret = av_buffersink_get_frame(buffersink_ctx, filtered_frame);

                if (ret < 0)
                {
                    check_error(ret);
                }

                QueryPerformanceCounter(&currentTime);

                double elapsedTime = (currentTime.QuadPart - lastTime.QuadPart) * 1000000.0 / frequency.QuadPart;

                if (elapsedTime > 0.0 && elapsedTime < frameTimeinUs)
                {
                    uSleep(frameTimeinUs - elapsedTime, frequency);
                }

                SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, nullptr, filtered_frame->data[0], filtered_frame->linesize[0]);
                SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
                SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, nullptr, nullptr);
                SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

                QueryPerformanceCounter(&lastTime);

                swap_uv_planes(filtered_frame);

                ret = sws_scale_frame(img_convert_ctx, pVideoFrame, filtered_frame);

                if (ret < 0)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Scaling frame for Intel QS Encoder did fail!" << '\n';
                    return -1;
                }

                if (av_hwframe_transfer_data(pHardwareFrame, pVideoFrame, 0) < 0)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Error transferring frame data to hw frame!" << '\n';
                    return -1;
                }

                pHardwareFrame->pts = frameCount++;

                ret = avcodec_send_frame(pVideoCodecContext, pHardwareFrame);

                if (ret < 0)
                {
                    std::cerr << "Error sending a frame for encoding" << '\n';
                    check_error(ret);
                }

                av_packet_unref(pVideoPacket);

                while (ret >= 0)
                {
                    ret = avcodec_receive_packet(pVideoCodecContext, pVideoPacket);

                    if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    if (ret < 0)
                    {
                        std::cerr << "Error during encoding" << '\n';
                        return 1;
                    }

                    av_packet_rescale_ts(pVideoPacket, pVideoCodecContext->time_base, pVideoStream->time_base);

                    pVideoPacket->stream_index = pVideoStream->index;

                    ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(pVideoFormatContext, pVideoPacket);

                    check_error(ret);

                    av_packet_unref(pVideoPacket);
                }

                av_packet_unref(pFrameGrabberPacket);
                av_frame_free(&filtered_frame);
            }
        }
    }

    av_write_trailer(pVideoFormatContext);
    av_buffer_unref(&pHardwareDeviceContextRef);
    avcodec_free_context(&pVideoCodecContext);
    avio_closep(&pVideoFormatContext->pb);
    avformat_free_context(pVideoFormatContext);
    av_packet_free(&pVideoPacket);

    avcodec_free_context(&pFrameGrabberCodecContext);
    av_frame_free(&pFrameGrabberFrame);
    av_packet_free(&pFrameGrabberPacket);
    avformat_close_input(&pFrameGrabberFormatContext);

    return 0;
}


The console / log output running the code:
[in @ 00000288ee494f40] Setting 'video_size' to value '1920x1080'
[in @ 00000288ee494f40] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value 'yuv420p'
[in @ 00000288ee494f40] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/25'
[in @ 00000288ee494f40] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '1/1'
[in @ 00000288ee494f40] w:1920 h:1080 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/25 fr:0/1 sar:1/1 csp:unknown range:unknown
[overlay_in @ 00000288ff1013c0] Setting 'video_size' to value '165x165'
[overlay_in @ 00000288ff1013c0] Setting 'pix_fmt' to value 'bgr24'
[overlay_in @ 00000288ff1013c0] Setting 'time_base' to value '1/25'
[overlay_in @ 00000288ff1013c0] Setting 'pixel_aspect' to value '1/1'
[overlay_in @ 00000288ff1013c0] w:165 h:165 pixfmt:bgr24 tb:1/25 fr:0/1 sar:1/1 csp:unknown range:unknown
[format @ 00000288ff1015c0] Setting 'pix_fmts' to value 'yuv420p'
[overlay @ 00000288ff101880] Setting 'x' to value 'W-w'
[overlay @ 00000288ff101880] Setting 'y' to value 'H-h'
[overlay @ 00000288ff101880] Setting 'enable' to value 'between(t,0,20)'
[overlay @ 00000288ff101880] Setting 'format' to value 'yuv420'
[auto_scale_0 @ 00000288ff101ec0] w:iw h:ih flags:'' interl:0
[format @ 00000288ff1015c0] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scale_0' between the filter 'overlay_in' and the filter 'format'
[auto_scale_1 @ 00000288ee4a4cc0] w:iw h:ih flags:'' interl:0
[overlay @ 00000288ff101880] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scale_1' between the filter 'format' and the filter 'overlay'
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000288ee495c80] query_formats: 5 queried, 6 merged, 6 already done, 0 delayed
[auto_scale_0 @ 00000288ff101ec0] w:165 h:165 fmt:bgr24 csp:gbr range:pc sar:1/1 -> w:165 h:165 fmt:yuv420p csp:unknown range:unknown sar:1/1 flags:0x00000004
[auto_scale_1 @ 00000288ee4a4cc0] w:165 h:165 fmt:yuv420p csp:unknown range:unknown sar:1/1 -> w:165 h:165 fmt:yuva420p csp:unknown range:unknown sar:1/1 flags:0x00000004
[overlay @ 00000288ff101880] main w:1920 h:1080 fmt:yuv420p overlay w:165 h:165 fmt:yuva420p
[overlay @ 00000288ff101880] [framesync @ 00000288ff1019a8] Selected 1/25 time base
[overlay @ 00000288ff101880] [framesync @ 00000288ff1019a8] Sync level 2

I tried to change the index / order of how the two different frames become pushed into the filter graph. Once I got a frame out of the graph but with the dimensions of the overlay image, not with the dimensions of the grabbed frame from the grabber card. So I suppose I am doing something wrong building up the filter graph.
To verify that the FFmpeg build contains all necessary modules I ran that procedure via FFmpeg executable in console and it worked and the result was as expected.
The command-line producing the expected output is following:
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="MZ0380 PCI, Analog 01 Capture" -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 25 -pixel_format yuv420p -loglevel debug -i "C:\temp\overlay.bmp" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=W-w:H-h:enable='between(t,0,20)'" -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4


Does it work on the command line?

@DaBler Yes, as I wrote in the last sentence it works well running it on command line.

Can you show the full command you use to run ffmpeg?

@DaBler I updated the question with the command line which produces the expected output.

I do not see av_buffersink_get_frame anywhere in your code.

It might be that the decoder is not producing a frame which causes EAGAIN.

@DaBler Yes - this was only the code of the filter graph init function. I updated the question with the complete prototype code which does some more stuff like preview and encoding. The decoder is working fine - the raw YUV420P frames can be stored as yuv video and so on. And the bitmap is already raw and fine too.

@DaBler Could you take a look on the sources already?
